# How to print internal information for OKI C3300 laser printer

Tags: printer

I would like print internal information about my OKI C3300 printer.

When I press "OnLine" for a few seconds, it's printing an information page but without any details that I would like to see, like:

- total pages printed
- toner usage
- other information about condition of replacement elements – for example the heating element

Answer (score 3):

1. I reset the network configuration by pushing the small reset button on the back of the printer (near to the RJ45 port), then I turned it off and on again.
2. Now it says hello to my DHCP server and get an IP address.
3. From OKI I downloaded an application called *Network Card Setup*, and it allowed me to change the password, and log into web configuration.
4. On the front page I got the information about toner usage.
5. The default admin password is the three last octets (6 chars) of the MAC address, without any separators (`:`) and the username is `admin`.
6. After logging in, I could see the information about supplies.

Comment: Marc: You can accept your own answer. That will prevent the post from getting bumped to to front page now and then. (which is done automatically with a few post per hour by 'community').

Answer (score 3):

You can print demo page and status page just using the online button of the printer.

- 3 seconds (before the LED blinks) prints status page
- more than 3 sec. (LED blinks) print demo page

Answer (score 0):

You could try connecting to the printer admin web page and viewing info there, and then printing that page

Comment: Yes, i connect but i can't find her ip address :>
I check ->  nmap -sP 192.168.0.1/24
and nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24  but she's not answering...